# Nested integrals formula?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Assuming that $f$ is integrable, does the following hold:

$∫_a^x f(y) [∫_a^x f(y) [\cdots [∫_a^x f(y) dy] dy] dy] dy = [∫_a^x f(y) dy]^n$?

If so, would induction be the way to prove it? Or is there a simple counterexample?

My thoughts go something along the lines of:

Let $F(y)=\int f(y) dy$, then $∫_a^x f(y) dy =F(x)-F(a)$. Since this is independent of $y$ we can factor outside of the next integral. Repeating this $n$ times we have the right hand side of the claim. Seems plausible, but again, there might be issues?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: an you do the case $n=2$?